# Type of instance var. when create instance of subclass which extends abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class

If you implement an interface and create an instance, the type of instance variable is USUALLY interface name. Which means

```
public interface MyIntefrace {
     void method();
}
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
     void method() { System.out.println(); }
}

public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 1) usually the type of instance var is MyInterface  
        MyInterface instance = new MyClass();    
        instance.method();

        // 2) you can use MyClass for instance var type though
        // but usually 1) is preferred in interface case
        MyClass instance2 = new MyClass(); 
    }  
}
```

But how about the abstract class? instance variable type can be either abstract class or its subclass.

Wondering which one is preferred, 3) or 4) in code below?

Or is there any rule to use only either of them in abstract class case?

Which means is there a case when I need to use 3) or 4) only?

```
public abstract class MyAbstract {
  abstract void method();
  void method2() {
    System.out.println();
  }
}

public class MyClass extends MyAbstract {

  void method() {
    System.out.println("abstract method");
  }

  @Override
  void method2() {
    System.out.println("method");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // 3) 
    MyAbstract instance = new MyClass();
    instance.method();
    instance.method2();

    // 4)
    MyClass instance2 = new MyClass();
    instance2.method();
    instance2.method2();
  }
}
```

Comment: Lowest common denominator - What does the API call for? What does you code need? `MyAbstract` or `MyClass`?  There might be a good reason to use `MyClass` in your code, but the rest of the API should rely on `MyAbstract` to decouple it from the implementation details - so the answer is, it depends

Comment: Another consideration in both cases is, does the higher level order provide the functionality you need?  It's conceivable that the implementation provides functionality not described in the parents which you need before you pass the instance to some other part of the API which only relies on instances of the parent contracts